# How to handle bulk number push notification?

Tags: web, websocket, push-notification

As the title mentioned above, I have a challenge that needs to overcome. I have a web application with volume more than 50k traffic. We have new requirement to implement push notification recently. Now my concern mostly are related to web application push notification and I know push notification for mobile device can use GCM to handle. I have done many research so far and I got "Websocket", "Server-Sent-Event" are in my list. Before implementing these technologies, I have some concern?

Will these technology make server down if websocket or sse publish too many connection (Maybe 50k or 100k)? As I know these technology are "keep-alive" connection.

Security, as I experience with websocket before, I find no way to authenticate during the connection handshake. I need the connection established with valid jwt token only.

I appreciate someone can advice on these scenario.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you specifically mean by "push notification"? Do you need to send notifications to all users who are registered with your site, or only the ones which currently have your site open in a browser?

Comment: Yes.... Push notify to whoever connecting to the site. For those offline will get notify once they connect to the site.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can drop connection from server side if JWT is invalid, so no issue with authentication. With socket.io it's `socket.disconnect`
   https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket-disconnect-close
2. You can always make a farm of servers and load balance socket connections. How many connections you will be able to hold per server really depends on how much data you will transfer on that pipe and what server you have. Most livechat companies are using WS and i have built one by myself couple yrs ago. You just load balance connections. Make architecture stateless and you are good to go.

Comment: Lukas, thanks for your reply. Can you share probably how many connection established of WS that your application has and how many nodes you use to handle these?

Comment: @A1ucard no, I don't have the numbers. But 50k doesn't sound many. Just make some tests with your scenarios.